# Query JIRA to get FIX versions for the given JIRA issues

Tags: jira

I have a text file with the list of JIRA issue numbers. How can I get the "Fix Version/s" of those Issues? I don't know REST APIs. So, is there any other way to query this from JIRA. Please let me know.

JIRA.txt

```
INF-124
INF-742
INF-998
INF-362
```

Expected output

```
INF-124      PRJ 7.1
INF-742      APP 5.2 
INF-998      APP 5.3
INF-362      PRJ 7.2
```

Comment: You could Export an issue search to xml and/or csv (Excel)? But I would suggest to do it with the REST API - login to jira and try to put this in your browser to get started {base-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issue-key}?fields=fixVersions

Comment: @ LukeSolar : The API worked good. Thank you!
This returned a JSON-formatted output from which I grabbed the Fix version from the property named "name"
If you want you can give this as an answer (instead of comment) so I can accept  it and it might be useful for others who is looking for the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Export an issue search to xml and/or csv (Excel)?

But I would suggest to do it with the REST API - login to jira and try to put this in your browser to get started {base-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issue-key}?fields=fixVersions

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we use the following query in JQL - JIRA:
KEY in (INF-124, INF-742, INF-998, INF-362)

If your default columns in JIRA are Key and FixVersions, than you can get an xls file by export XLS current fields. You can even copy the link to that option so that you should have something like this:
http:///jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?jqlQuery=key+in+%28INF-124%2C+INF-742%2C+INF-998%2C+INF-362%29&tempMax=10000

Your exported excel file will have exactly your needed output.